# how can a firefox extension detect content-type of the page loaded?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, content-type, xpcom

since my extension's pageload is triggered even when I view css or js files, i want to add another check that triggers my extension only when the current page's content-type is text/html .

```
//eg: at my page load handler
function onPageload(){

  // only want to proceed if content-type reflects a text/html or */html page
  if ( contentTypeIsHtml() ){
    //continue here
  }
}
```

what should contentTypeIsHtml() do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the content type using the document.contentType property (this is not standard DOM, but is there to be used by extensions)

Comment: thanks, was going banana's trying to create an xpcom component, it's various interfaces and listened to every page ( not to forget scattered docs on xpcom over the years ). cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the source to the add-on JSONView, unzip the xpi and take a look at components/jsonview.js, towards the end of the source the add-on registers itself for the mime-type application/json. You could probably do something similar.

Comment: ya had a look at it. thankfully, i dont have to build xpcom, or streams or interfaces. got to understand how mozilla internally figures out content types though. document.contentType works great. thanks michael.